# Android app throws Fatal Exception when .commit() is called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am reasonably new to android fragments and am trying to make an app that loads a new fragment once the user clicks a Submit button. What I want to happen when the Submit button is clicked is that a new fragment is swapped for the existing fragment being displayed. LogCat shows the error happening when the commit() method is called. Any explanation as to why this error is thrown?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.flightfragmenttest;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Spinner modelInputSpinner, specInputSpinner;

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    GensetFragment genFrag = new GensetFragment();
    ResultsFragment resFrag = new ResultsFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragmentContainer) != null) {

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, genFrag).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void search(View v) {

        modelInputSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.modelSpinner);
        specInputSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.specSpinner);

        addModelItemSelectedListener();
        addSpecItemSelectedListener();

        genFrag.search(modelInputSpinner, specInputSpinner);

        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, resFrag);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void addSpecItemSelectedListener() {

        specInputSpinner
        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view, int position, long id) {

                //
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }

    private void addModelItemSelectedListener() {

        modelInputSpinner
        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }

}
```

First fragment

```
package com.example.flightfragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class GensetFragment extends Fragment {

    Genset userInput = new Genset();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genset, container,
                false);


        return rootView;
    }


    public void search(Spinner model, Spinner spec) {

            userInput.setModelNumber(model.getSelectedItem()
                    .toString());
            userInput.setSpecNumber(spec.getSelectedItem()
                    .toString());

            System.out.println(userInput.getModelNumber() + " " + userInput.getSpecNumber());

    }

}
```

Second Fragment

```
package com.example.flightfragmenttest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println("Step in to results");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_results, container, false);

        System.out.println("Step in to results");
        return rootView;
    }



}
```

LogCat

```
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): Process: com.example.flightfragmenttest, PID: 2982
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     ... 11 more
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:582)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     at com.example.flightfragmenttest.MainActivity.search(MainActivity.java:61)
06-09 11:36:00.494: E/AndroidRuntime(2982):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Post a stack trace from Logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reuse fragment transactions. Call `beginTransaction()` to create a new one.

Also, it's likely better to access the fragment manager only in `onCreate()` or later in the activity lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. I'd been wracking my brain and Google for days trying to find out the reason for the error!

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep a `FragmentTransaction` as a class member of your activity. Get a new `FragmentTransaction` every time you want to change the fragments, e.g.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, resFrag);
    .addToBackStack(null);
    .commit();
```